# How can i change the time constantly

Tags: python-3.x, azure-cosmosdb, python-datetime

Hi guys i am very new to python and i would very much appreciate some help on this matter, i have been trying to get the actual time with each record i send to the database but i think because it is a loop it seems to record the beginning time and loop it.

could anybody help me out with this?

HOW CAN I GET REAL TIME INSTEAD OF THE SAME TIME GETTING LOOPED

```
# Author: Aswin Ramamchandran
# Version: 1.1

from time import sleep
import datetime
import pymongo
import time

# This URL provides connection to the database
uri = blahblah

# initialising pymongo client
client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)

# Database where the records will be saved - reference to the database
db = client.Kostenanalyse

# Accessing the collection "latenz" from the Database
coll = db.latenz

#Defining the Start time
start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
start_time = start_time.isoformat()
end = time.perf_counter()



def create_latenz_data()-> dict:
 
 return {
       "Temperature" : "",
       "Time when packet was sent" : start_time,
       "Sensor A reading" : "",
       "Latency" : end,

}

#While loop 
while True:
    data = create_latenz_data()
    start = time.perf_counter()
    coll.insert_one(data)
    end = time.perf_counter() - start
    print('{:.6f}s for the calculation'.format(end))
    print(str(start_time) + 'Wrote data sample {} to collpipection {}'.format(data, 'latenz'))
    sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: move the start_time calculations inside your 'create_latenz_data' function??

Comment: Your script stores the `start_time` variable at load and does not change it. As you have used that same variable inside `while` loop and  inside `create_latenz_data()` I suggest replacing `start_time` with `datetime.datetime.now().isoformat() `directly so new time is picked everytime it is called.

Comment: @BijayRegmi Thank you so much that really helped, i had to change it also inside the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script stores the `start_time` variable at load and does not change it. As you have used that same variable inside while loop and inside `create_latenz_data()`, replacing `start_time` with `datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()` directly so new time is picked everytime it is called.

```
from time import sleep
import datetime
import pymongo
import time

# This URL provides connection to the database
uri = blahblah

# initialising pymongo client
client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)

# Database where the records will be saved - reference to the database
db = client.Kostenanalyse

# Accessing the collection "latenz" from the Database
coll = db.latenz


def create_latenz_data()-> dict:
 
 return {
       "Temperature" : "",
       "Time when packet was sent" : datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(),
       "Sensor A reading" : "",
       "Latency" : end,

}

#While loop 
while True:
    data = create_latenz_data()
    start = time.perf_counter()
    coll.insert_one(data)
    end = time.perf_counter() - start
    print('{:.6f}s for the calculation'.format(end))
    print(str(datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()) + 'Wrote data sample {} to collpipection {}'.format(data, 'latenz'))
    sleep(0.5)
```